# Por que dizemos "O gato comeu a sua língua?"

Tags: significado, etimologia, expressões, origem-histórica

Essa expressão é utilizada para indicar que alguém está quieto, sem falar.

Exemplo:

> Você não vai falar nada não? O gato comeu sua língua?

Mas por que dizemos isso? Alguma vez um gato realmente já comeu a língua de alguém, ou ao menos chegou a morder e a pessoa ficou sem conseguir falar?

Comment: Para alguém ter inventado  e o pessoal depois usar e compreender a expressão não é necessário que alguma vez um gato tenha mordido ou comido a língua a alguém. A interpretação é imediata: se um gato tivesse comida a língua, a pessoa não poderia falar. É claro que a pergunta é retórica: quem pergunta sabe que o 'mudo' tem a língua intacta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eu sabia que essa não era uma expressão portuguesa já que há também em inglês *cat got your tongue* mas vendo sua pergunta fui procurar e encontrei [esta página](http://www.historyextra.com/facts/why-we-say-%E2%80%98cat-got-your-tongue%E2%80%99).

Basicamente, ela diz que a origem formal é desconhecida mas sugere estar ligada ao ato de certos reis cortarem as línguas de certos condenados e darem-nas de comer aos animais... ou a atos de inquisição nos quais se cortavam as línguas às bruxas, dando de comer aos seus familiares (*familiar = animal místico das bruxas*).

A expressão inglesa aponta mais neste sentido = "O gato **ficou com** sua língua.

Answer (score 1):

Procurei no Google Books, e o exemplo mais antigo que encontrei da expressão é de 1959 (meu negrito em todas as citações):
[image]

Como se pode ver, em contexto, a expressão é imediatamente compreensível: se o gato tivesse comido a língua, a pessoa não poderia falar. Naturalmente a pergunta é retórica, e o absurdo de um gato ter comido a língua à pessoa contribui para o tom jocoso da expressão.

Agora podemos perguntar: porquê um gato e não outro animal? Provavelmente com razão, os gatos ganharam fama de ladrões. [*Gatuno* (Aulete)](http://www.aulete.com.br/gatuno) vem de *gato* por via do castelhano [(ver *gatuno* na Real Academia Espanhola)](http://dle.rae.es/?id=J0ZzY9D); [*gato* (Aulete 10)](http://www.aulete.com.br/gato) é também usado com o sentido de ‘ladrão’; e no Brasil usa-se mesmo a expressão ***o gato comeu*** relativamente a coisas que desapareceram sem explicação, como explicado no [*Portuguese-English Dictionary* de James L. Taylor (1970)](https://books.google.pt/books?id=pyylwqkVIUoC&pg=PA169&lpg=PA169&dq=%22o%20gato%20comeu%20the%20cat%20got%20it%22&source=bl&ots=JFJ8vevqIv&sig=3Px9eXr-pO46UkiNr6CA7pwbDU0&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiJ-K-QmLTOAhVEshQKHaXtCCoQ6AEIHTAA#v=onepage&q=%22o%20gato%20comeu%20the%20cat%20got%20it%22&f=false).

*O gato comeu sua língua* pode até ter começado por ser um uso especializado de *o gato comeu*. Encontramos expressão *o gato comeu*, ou a ideia em que se baseia, numa [lengalenga infantil:](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rk9YDzEOdiQ)

> Cadê o toicinho que estava aqui? — O gato comeu. — Cadê o gato? — Foi pró mato. — Cadê o mato? [Continua]

Esta lengalenga está atestada já em 1880 [(*Revista Brazileira*):](https://books.google.pt/books?id=0MRLAQAAMAAJ&q=%22gato%20comeu%22&dq=%22gato%20comeu%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiivJeWm7TOAhVDvxQKHcGHD0U4lgEQ6AEI-QEwIQ)

> O final disto todos conhecem: consiste em fazer cócegas pelo braço acima, perguntando pelo *toucinho* que estava na *palma da mão*, e que o *o gato* comeu e foi fugindo, etc.

E neste outro livro de 1897, uma cozinheira atribui ao gato a culpa pelo desaparecimento da manteiga:
[image]